# disable "cause validation" for dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating the same button twice: once on Page_Load, and another on: Page_PreRender. 
I expected to see the same behavior, however, the buttons created on Page_PreRender doesn't work the way intended. (i.e. property "causeValidation" remains true).

"I want to disable "causeValidation" for the button in page_preRender, and i want it there in PreRender. Also, I want the Button_Click function to execute for both buttons, currently it does only for button created on "Page_load" ".

I am looking for a **solution or an explanation** for this behavior.

Thank You.

Take a look at the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        form1.Controls.Add(GetButton("Button1", "Click"));
    }

    protected void page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.Controls.Add(GetButton("Button3", "Click"));
    }

    private Button GetButton(string id, string name)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = name;
        b.ID = id;
        b.CausesValidation = false;
        b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
        b.OnClientClick = "ButtonClick('" + b.ClientID + "')";
        return b;
    }

    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), ((Button)sender).ID, "<script>alert('Button_Click');</script>");
        Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + ((Button)sender).ID + " was clicked");
    }
```

and here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonClick(buttonId) {
        alert("Button " + buttonId + " clicked from javascript");
    }
</script>
```

**Update:**
let me add this: Both buttons execute the client's script. This means that buttons are created. "see function GetButton() ".

Also, the reason why i have the button created "on preRender" instead of "on Page_Load" is that: if i have a form used to enter data into a table **dynamically**, and i add the data on button click, the the page will PostBack first, then execute the event handler, (i.e the data is added to the table but will show on NEXT postBack). So, PreRender is used to show the table AFTER it is updated by the button_click event.

I hope this addition is useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

As you see from this image, that represents asp.net page life cycle (copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)), `Event Handling` precedes `PreRender`. So, in order to fire `Button_Click` the button itself has to be created before the `Event Handling`. Page PreInit is a preferred place to add dynamic controls.

you can see it yourself, just add breakpoints at `Page_Load`, `Page_PreRender`, `Button_Click`. notice the order there are triggered?

Comment: Nice explanation, but let me add this: Both buttons execute the client's script. This means that buttons are created. "see function GetButton() ".

Comment: Also, the reason why i have the button created "on preRender" instead of "on Page_Load" is that: if i have a form used to enter data into a table **dynamically**, and i add the data on button click, the the page will PostBack first, then execute the event handler, (i.e the data is added to the table but will show on NEXT postBack). So, PreRender is used to show the table AFTER it is updated by the button_click event. 
I hope this addition is useful

Comment: @MAltakrori yes both buttons exist on page, and yes clientside script will execute. but when the page is submitted to server, page starts *new life* and when it comes to the part of event handling there will be no button3. as for second comment - didn't really got what you are trying to achieve. I think you are after clientside scripting. perhaps JS will suit you neeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Check asp.net [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx): events are handled after page load and **before** PreRender.

ASP.NET cannot handle an event involving a control that does not yet exists.

Comment: If i got you right, then i agree with you but I have added the event handler on PreRender, so this means when i click the button the event handler should execute the function attached. Am I right ?

Comment: No, because when it's time to handle the event with EventTarget = Button3, there is no control with that ID so it is skipped.